# ¿Por qué me muestra como valor 0 si cada radio button tiene su respectivo valor diferente? TKINTER

Tags: python, tkinter

este es mi codigo y la verdad no entiendo porque siempre sale 0 si cada boton tiene como valor un valor diferente.

Gracias por tu interés en ayudarme.

```
def crud():
    def obtener_valor():
        print("Valor seleccionado:", var.get())
        
    root_crud = Tk()
    root_crud.title('MU - Mascotas Unidas V.01') #TITULO
    root_crud.iconbitmap('Recursos\MU_icon.ico')
    root_crud.geometry("1020x500")
    root_crud.configure(bg="#F3F0ED")
    root_crud.resizable(False,False)
    global e1
    global e2
    global e3
    global e4
    #fg='#BE8A62', bg="white", font=('Bellefair', 40 )

    Label(root_crud, text="ID de las Mascota").place(x=10, y=10)
    Label(root_crud, text="Nombre de la Mascota").place(x=10, y=40)
    Label(root_crud, text="Nombre del Dueño").place(x=10, y=70)
    Label(root_crud, text="Raza de su Mascota").place(x=10, y=100)
    Label(root_crud, text="Estado: ").place(x=300, y=10)
    var = IntVar()

    radio_button1 = Radiobutton(root_crud, text="Opción 1", variable=var, value=1)
    radio_button2 = Radiobutton(root_crud, text="Opción 2", variable=var, value=2)
    radio_button3 = Radiobutton(root_crud, text="Opción 3", variable=var, value=3)

    boton_obtener_valor = Button(root_crud, text="Obtener Valor", command=obtener_valor)

    root_crud.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En sí no está completo el codigo pero creo que se entiende.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque no lo muestras en tu código, este error suele estar causado por usar mas de una ventana principal y ejecutar su mainloop de forma concurrente. Si usas `crud` para abrir una ventana secundaria dentro de tu app principal, simplificando algo así:

```
from tkinter import *


def crud():
    def obtener_valor():
        print("Valor seleccionado:", var.get())
        
    root_crud = Tk()
    var = IntVar()

    Radiobutton(root_crud, text="Opción 1", variable=var, value=1).pack()
    Radiobutton(root_crud, text="Opción 2", variable=var, value=2).pack()
    Radiobutton(root_crud, text="Opción 3", variable=var, value=3).pack()

    Button(root_crud, text="Obtener Valor", command=obtener_valor).pack()

    root_crud.mainloop()
    
app = Tk()
Button(app, text="Abrir crud", command=crud).pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Tendrás justamente el problema que describes.

---

### Nunca debes tener más de una ventana principal (instancia de `tkinter.Tk`) y más de un mainloop ejecutándose simultáneamente en una misma aplicación (proceso).

---

Cuando varios mainloops se ejecutan de forma concurrente pasan cosas inesperadas... El mainllop "interno" al ejecutarse interfiere con la ejecución del externo, interfiriendo a su vez en la respuesta a los eventos y la actualización de los widgets que dependen del mainloop "externo", en este caso la `IntVar`.

Ten en en cuenta que aun si has cerrado las ventanas abiertas previamente con `tkinter.Tk`, o incluso si no has invocado sus mainloops antes de crear la instancia de `IntVar`, el problema seguirá ocurriendo igualmente hasta que no se destruyan todas las instancias de `tkinter.Tk` previas (por ejemplo, ejecutado sus métodos `destroy`).

Debes siempre crear una sola ventana principal y para las ventanas secundarias usar siempre `tkinter.Toplevel`, que usara el mismo mainloop de la ventana padre. Volviendo al ejemplo simplificado, esto resuelve el problema:

```
from tkinter import *


def crud():
    def obtener_valor():
        print("Valor seleccionado:", var.get())
    
    root_crud = Toplevel(app)
    # Si quieres evitar que se interaccione con la ventana principal
    root_crud.grab_set() 
    
    var = IntVar()

    Radiobutton(root_crud, text="Opción 1", variable=var, value=1).pack()
    Radiobutton(root_crud, text="Opción 2", variable=var, value=2).pack()
    Radiobutton(root_crud, text="Opción 3", variable=var, value=3).pack()

    Button(root_crud, text="Obtener Valor", command=obtener_valor).pack()

    
app = Tk()
Button(app, text="Abrir crud", command=crud).pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Básicamente es hacer que  `root_crud` sea una instancia de `Toplevel` y pasarle a la misma una referencia a la ventana principal (en este caso es `app`, pero seguramente sera otro nombre en tu caso). Obviamente también debes eliminar la linea
`root_crud.mainloop()`.

A diferencia de `tkinter.Tk` puedes tener las ventanas `Toplevel` que quieras.

Comment: La verdad estoy muy sorprendido de todo tus conocimientos. Me has ayudado bastante y te lo agradezco un MONTÓN.